# div elements will not line up properly (side by side)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

The code below is from an ASP MVC3 view. The first two "container" `div` elements (`topDiv` and `middleDiv`) work just fine. The `fieldsets` align properly left-to-right. However, the `bottomDiv` element does not. In this "container" the `leftDiv` is lined up all the way to the right of the `BigDiv` "container", and the `rightDiv` winds up below the `leftDiv` elements AND on the left hand side of the screen.

Obviously not so great w/HTML/CSS positioning (none of these div elements have an CSS attached to them at the moment, just trying to get everything lined up), so if someone could tell me what was going on that would be greatly appreciated.

Since there's over 1000 lines of HTML/Razor syntax in all the `fieldsets` combined I appended that area of the code. If anyone needs to see a specific `fieldset` I'll be glad to post.

```
<div id="BigDiv" style="clear:both;">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOperator)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceNumber)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReferenceType)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ExtRepType) 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Region)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.INDDist)
    <div id="topDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="AgentTypeFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div> 
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DistributionFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="middleDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="BasicFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DRMFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottomDiv">
        <div class="LeftDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="AddressFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>

            <fieldset id="CommunicationFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
        <div class="RightDiv" style="width: 450px; float:left;">
            <fieldset id="DSSAgentIds" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>

            <fieldset id="DSSFields" style="width: 400px;">...</fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to Search", "Index", "Agent")  
    </p>
</div>
```

Here is a screen shot of the outcome. `Producer Info` and `Distribution` are the left and right `divs` of the `topDiv`. `Basics` and `DRM` are compose the `middleDiv`. `Addresses` corresponds (obviously) to the `AddressFields` `fieldset` in the `bottomDiv`.

[image]

Here is a screen shot of the bottom of the page. `DSS Agent ID` is the first `fieldset` in the `RightDiv` of the `bottomDiv` element.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this tag to the `bottomDiv` solved the issue

```
<div id="bottomDiv" style="clear:both;">
```

Not sure why though. if someone can give a better answer would love to accept. Thx